# How to plot two lines with Torch gnuplot?

Tags: lua, gnuplot, torch

I have two data sets `x,y`, `x1,y1`. I want to plot them all in one figure.

```
require 'gnuplot'

local x,y,x1,y1 = unpack(data)
gnuplot.xlabel('PPL')
gnuplot.ylabel('Epoch #')
gnuplot.plot({x,y},{x1,y1})
```

[image]

This works well, but I'd like to have straight lines instead of dotted lines. Also, I want to include a legend in top right corner.
Alas, whatever combination I tried, it does not work.

```
gnuplot.plot({x,y},{x1,y1},'-')
gnuplot.plot('1','2',{x,y},{x1,y1},'-')
gnuplot.plot({'1','2',{x,y},{x1,y1},'-'})
```

How can I plot two lines and add a legend in one figure with **gnuplot**?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://github.com/torch/gnuplot/blob/master/doc/plotline.md) the following should work:

```
gnuplot.plot({'first', x, y, '-'}, 
    {'second', x1, y1, '-'})
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, it doesn't. I tried this notation.

Answer (score 0):

torchstyle variable contains: "set style data linespoints", which sets the style that data are plotted to linespoints.

You need to write this command:

```
gnuplot.raw('set style data lines')
```